# Executing PowerShell scripts in .NET6 application fails with Active Directory Module

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, .net-6.0

I am trying to execute PowerShell scripts in my .NET 6 application (hosted on IIS). Simple scripts (printing Hello World) work fine. However, once I add the following line to the script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq 'admin'"
```

(*could be anything AD related*).

I get this seemingly unrelated error message:

```cs
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.\r\n ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The 'system.serviceModel/diagnostics' configuration section cannot be created. The machine.config file is missing information. Verify that this configuration section is properly registered and that you have correctly spelled the section name. For Windows Communication Foundation sections, run ServiceModelReg.exe -i to fix this error.\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetSectionNoTrace(String sectionPath)\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.DiagnosticSection.UnsafeGetSectionNoTrace()\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility..cctor()\r\n   
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory..ctor()\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Type channelType)\r\n  
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.InitializeChannel[TChannel](TChannel& channel, ChannelFactory`1& chFactory, String endpointName, CommunicationException& commException)\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.SearchAnObject(ADSearchRequest request)\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.Search(ADSearchRequest request)\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADWebServiceStoreAccess.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.IADSyncOperations.Search(ADSessionHandle handle, ADSearchRequest request)\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObjectSearcher.GetRootDSE()\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADCmdletBase`1.GetRootDSE()\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADCmdletBase`1.GetConnectedStore()\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADCmdletBase`1.GetCmdletSessionInfo()\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADGetCmdletBase`3.ADGetCmdletBaseBeginCSRoutine()\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.CmdletSubroutinePipeline.Invoke()\r\n  
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADCmdletBase`1.BeginProcessing()
```

The executing user permissions are correct and the Active Directoy Module is available.

I haven't changed the `machine.config` file.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well usually running AD commands your user needs to be part of the domain. Does yours?

Comment: An HTTP client has limited access to the IIS resources such as the file system.  The HTTP server only has client privilege of GUEST which cannot read or write the IIS file system.

Comment: @Eldar Yes, running the script manually works (same User as the IIS Server)

Comment: You are attempting to run .NET Framework based code on .NET 6 runtime, which can then work or break in all possible ways. You can read more from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/?view=windowsserver2022-ps "If you want to use this module in PowerShell 7, please see PowerShell 7 module compatibility" is the hint, because PowerShell 7 is a .NET Core based application. However, not sure if you execute PowerShell scripts in .NET 6 how to enable such compatibility mode (shelling out to PowerShell 5.1) yourself.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, I think you might be right, too bad I cant figure out how to force v5.1 in order to verify this

Comment: @LexLi Update: So I managed to start a v5.1 PS by simply invoking a new process and everything seems to be working now. You were absolutely correct, PS v7 caused all of the cryptic errors. v5.1 works perfectly. Thank you for your input on this. Will post an answer once im 100% certain everything works.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out what the problem was, i'm running into this exact issue